# connect paypal button to product selection on dropdown

Tags: php, paypal

I am making an eCommerce store in PHP. I have nearly everything ready and I am now thinking about a Paypal button. I have got the code from Paypal for the the button.

I did a test run and it does transfer money over, however, I do not know how to connect it to product id from database. I have a range of products in different styles. Ie - shirts in different sizes.

Could someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks